# Azure blob DownloadToStream takes too long

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download a file from Azure blob, but in 0.1% cases it just hangs at the blockBlob.DownloadToStream(...) for more than 10 mins. Is there a way I can timeout this function in 2 mins?

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
   blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream, null, new BlobRequestOptions()
   {
        ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)
   });
   string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure the timeout for the whole DownloadToStream operation. For example, you can set [MaximumExecutionTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.maximumexecutiontime.aspx) to 120 seconds (this is for whole DownloadToStream operation), [ServerTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.servertimeout.aspx) to 30 seconds (this is for each REST call), and specify a [RetryPolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.retrypolicy.aspx) ([ExponentialRetry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.retrypolicies.exponentialretry.aspx) or [LinearRetry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.retrypolicies.linearretry.aspx), this is for each REST call) to enable retrying while a request times out or fails. By doing so, each individual [Get Blob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179440.aspx) REST call will be limited to 30 seconds at server side (retry policy will take effect if encountering server timeout issue), and the whole DownloadToStream operation will be limited to 2 minutes at client side.

Please refer to the code sample below. Note: The [BlobRequestOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.aspx) object only needs to be constructed once, then you can use it for all blob related operations below.

```
        var maxRetryCount = 3;
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        var blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
        {
            ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), maxRetryCount),
        };

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream, null, blobRequestOptions);
        }
```

Comment: In order to download blob with high throughput, I'd suggest you to try Azure Storage Data Movement Library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library

Comment: Oh ok Thanks Zhaoxing, but how to consume the "AzureStorageData Movement Library" ? Can you provide some sample code or property to download a file as a stream like "DownloadToStreamAsync". So I do not know to achieve this due to I am very new to Azure Storage. If you are ready to help mean, then I will create a new query.

Comment: Please see the code sample here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/95742181a8d3751eff70bfff837412b3db6df343/samples/DataMovementSamples/DataMovementSamples/Samples.cs#L185

Comment: No, BeginDownloadToStream and EndDownloadToStream is just the legacy asynchronous version of DownloadToStreamAsync, they must be used in the same time and share the same performance as DownloadToStreamAsync. You can see more details of BeginXXX and EndXXX pattern of C# in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/

Comment: Thank you for your comment and valuable time @Zhaoxing Lu.

Comment: And one more thing, I am not able to find the details of Beginxxx & Endxxx from the above mentioned article. Could you please ping the exact site? so I can explain it to my team with proof. @ Zhaoxing Lu

Comment: In the article above, the example methods are BeginRead and EndRead. It's a standard (but legacy) async programming pattern, which has been replaced by async/await pattern mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! I also got the following piece of code to retry download the blob after a timeout.

```
 CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
 var cts = new CancellationTokenSource((int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30 * (retryCount + 1)).TotalMilliseconds);

 using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
 {
    Task task = blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream, cts.Token);
    await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (!task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());                            
    }
    else if (task.IsCanceled)
    {
        retryCount++;
        Console.WriteLine("Task cancelled happened for blob: {0}. Increasing timeout to: {1} sec", blobName, retryCount * 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd still suggest to leverage official support of RetryPolicy since you can just pass in a BlobRequestOptions instead of writing retry code for each request.

Comment: I've added a code sample to my answer, please check it. Leverage the existing options in Azure Storage Client Library is the best practice. If my answer can indeed help you in this question, please mark it as Answered, thanks!